# How to change brightness of buffered image?

Tags: java, javafx, colors, bufferedimage, brightness

So basically I'm loading image to my javafx application, and after clicking '+' or '-' button I want to increase or decrease image brightness. Currently my method looks like this:

```
  public void increaseBrightness(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    BufferedImage imageToBright = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(imageView.getImage(), null);
    for(int x=0; x<imageToBright.getWidth(); x++){
      for(int y=0; y<imageToBright.getHeight(); y++){
        int rgba = imageToBright.getRGB(x,y);
        Color color = new Color(rgba, true);
        color = new Color(
          validatePixelValue(color.getRed() + 10),
          validatePixelValue(color.getGreen() + 10),
          validatePixelValue(color.getBlue() + 10)
        );
        imageToBright.setRGB(x,y, color.getRGB());
      }
    }
    imageView.setImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(imageToBright, null));
  }

  private int validatePixelValue(int value){
    if(value > 255){
      value = 255;
    } else if(value < 0){
      value = 0;
    }
    return value;
  }
```

It works but the problem is when pixel value will go above 255 (for example 251 + 10 will end up as 255 not 261) his value is lost - I mean when I decrease brightness in the same way as in the method above I won't have the same value (255 - 10 instead of 261 - 10).
Can you tell me what is the correct approach to this problem? I am only allowed to work on pixels, can't use any external libraries.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should not unneccessarily mix JavaFX and Swing. You could achieve all of the above by using a WritableImage and a PixelReader from JavaFX.

Answer (score 1):

The range for Red, Green, and Blue is from 0 to 255, so you can't add greater values than that. Check the official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color(int,%20int,%20int)) for Color

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to use methods from [Color](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html) (`javafx.scene.paint.Color`)

Example :

```
Color rgb = Color.color(R,G,B);
//OR
Color rgba = new Color(R,G,B,A);

rgb=rgb.brighter(); // Increases brightness
rgb=rgb.darker(); // Decreases brightness
```